# Relation between limit inferior of function and limit inferior of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space, $f$ is a function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $(x_n)$ is a sequence which converges to $a$. How to proof this inequality?
$$\liminf_{x \to a} f(x)\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$$

I tried to find it in some books, but i couldn't find any explanation about that inequality and definition of $\liminf_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$.

Any help will be so appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129668/discussion-on-question-by-mathlearner-relation-between-limit-inferior-of-functio).

Comment: Can we prove that one of the sets has less limit points than the other?

Comment: @wakem I used to think so, but then I got stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the contrary, i.e. $\liminf_{x \to c} f(x)> \liminf_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)$, then, there exists $k\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\liminf_{x \to c} f(x)> k > \liminf_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\liminf_{x \to c}f(x)>k$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
  &\sup_{\varepsilon>0}\{\inf\{f(x):x\in B(c,\varepsilon)\cap X -\{c\}\}\}>k,\\
  \Rightarrow & \inf\{f(x):x\in B(c,\varepsilon)\cap X -\{c\}\}>k,\\
  \Rightarrow & f(x)>k, \quad \text{for all}\,x\in B(c,\varepsilon).
  \end{align*}
Then, since $(x_n)$ converges to $c$, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$, such that for all $n\geq n_0$ we have $x_n\in B(c,\varepsilon)$. So, for all $n\geq n_0$, we have $f(x_n)>k$. Therefore, for all $\varepsilon>0$, $\inf \{f(x_n):x_n\in B(c,\varepsilon),n\geq n_0\}\geq k.$ Thus, $$\liminf_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)=\sup\{\inf \{f(x_n):x_n\in B(c,\varepsilon),n\geq n_0\}\}\geq k.$$ It is a contradiction with $k > \liminf_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)$, so we must have $\liminf_{x \to c} f(x)\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty} f(x_n).$

Comment: @Joe I have done, is there any mistakes?

Comment: I think you're close, but I believe there are some mistakes and/or parts that aren't clear. (1) just because the infimum is < c doesn't mean $f(x_n)<c$ for all $n\ge k$; it only means that $f(x_n)<c$ infinitely often. Then, when you wrote to choose $N =\max\{n,n_0\}$, it wasn't clear to me what $n$ is.

Comment: @Joe correction: because the infimum is $<c$, then there exists $n_* \geq k $, such that $f(x_{n_*})<c$. And then choose $N=\{n_*, n_0\}$. If my correction is right, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: If you start from the $\lim\inf x_n$ side, I think you'll need to use that $x_n < c$ infinitely often, so that you can argue that $\forall \epsilon> 0$, since there are only finitely many $x_n \notin B(a,\epsilon)$, there must be $x_n \in B(a,\epsilon)$ with $f(x_n)<c$

Comment: @Joe Oh, i think i got the point. I have edited my answer again.

Comment: I think you have a correct proof (the idea of the proof), but that it still has some errors in the write up. When you write $\Rightarrow \{\inf\{f(x_n):n\geq k\}\}<c$, I don't know what that means, because you're not taking the supremum over $k$ any more, but there's still a $k$. And when you write $\Rightarrow f(x_n)<c$, that is stating that $f(x_n)<c$ for all $n>n_0$, which isn't necessarily true. I would just take both of those lines out, and go straight to $f(x_n)<c$ infinitely often. Then again later in your proof, make sure to state that $f(x_n)<c$ infinitely often, not in general.

Comment: @Joe so, I didn't need apply the definition of limit inferior of sequence to $\liminf_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$? To be honest, I didn't know the definition of $\liminf_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$ exactly..

Comment: You have the definition of $\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$ in your proof. It's $\sup_{k\geq 1}\{\inf\{f(x_n):n\geq k\}\}<c$. I would go straight from that to "$\implies f(x_n)<c$ infinitely often", but to be more explicit (add intermediate steps), you could instead first put "$\implies \forall k \geq 1 \, \exists j>k, \, f(x_j) < c$. If you're not following, it may help to define the sequence $b_k = \inf\{f(x_n):n\geq k\}$, and to realize that $b_n$ must be nondecreasing (why?)

Comment: @Joe because from the definition of sequence $b_k = \inf\{f(x_n): n\geq k\}$, we get that sequence $(b_k)$ is monotone increasing. Then, a monotone increasing sequence will be converge to $\sup\{b_k: k\geq 1\}$ and we get $\liminf_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)=\lim_{k\to \infty} b_k < c$. 
So, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k>N$, we have $f(x_k)<c$. 

Then, after the statement above, is it enough to conclude that $f(x_n)<c$ infinitely often?

Comment: If you know that $b_k$ is nondecreasing, and $\lim_{k\to\infty}b_k < c$, then you know that $b_k < c$ for all $k$, which is enough to know that $f(x_n)<c$ infinitely often (which is what you need), BUT do not say that "there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that FOR ALL $k>N$ we have $f(x_k)<c$", because that does not follow. We only have $f(x_n)<c$ infinitely often. Consider if $f(x_k)$ is $-1/k$ for odd $k$ and $2$ for even $k$. Then $b_k$ is $-1/k$ for odd $k$ and $-1/(k+1)$ for even $k$, with $\lim_{k\to\infty}b_k = 0$, and so $f(x_k)<0$ infinitely often, but $f(x_k)=2$ infinitely often also

Comment: @Joe oh, okay. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @joe Sorry, if ask again. Based on your comment,  you said "if you start from  $\liminf_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)$ side, ..." Then, I am curious how about if I start from $\liminf_{x \to a} f(x)>c$. What do you think if the proof start from $\liminf_{x \to a} f(x)>c$? I think it will be simpler.  I have tried it, but I am not sure my attempt is correct or not :(

Comment: If $\lim\inf_{x\to a} f(x)>c$, then $\exists \epsilon>0,\, \forall x \in B(a,\epsilon),\, f(x)>c$. Since $x_n \to a,\, \exists k \in \mathbb{N},\, \forall n>k,\, x_n \in B(a,\epsilon)$. Therefore $\forall n>k,\, f(x_n)>c$, so that $\lim\inf f(x_n) >c$.

Comment: Okay, i think it is simpler and easier to understand than before, thank you :D

Comment: You're welcome.